# How to find a path in a graph that does not contain nodes from a set?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I have a **directed** and **unweighted graph** `G = { V, E }`.

Additionally, I have a set `X` which is a subset of the vertices `V`. This set denotes special **forbidden nodes**.

I want to **find a path** from a given **source** node `v` to a **destination** node `u` but the path must not contain any of the forbidden nodes in `X`.

How can I find such a path but avoid the nodes at the same time?

edit :
this is my final solution

```py
    def notPassTroughX(G: Graph, X: list, u: Node, v: Node):
    
        for x in X:
            x.set_color(color.black)

        return not G.bfs(u, v) and G.bfs(u, v)
```

Comment: Delete the "forbidden" nodes from the graph.

Comment: Alternatively ignore X nodes when seeking adjacent nodes (neighbors) like you ignore visited nodes.

Answer (score 2):

### Ignore nodes in `X`

Grab your favorite path-finding algorithm and simply ignore any node in `X`.

Since you tagged with *"depth-first-search"* let us take a look at that algorithm (pseudocode taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)):

```
let S be a stack
S.push(v)
while S is not empty do
    v = S.pop()
    if v is not labeled as discovered then
        label v as discovered
        for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
            S.push(w)
```

All you have to do is to modify the edge relaxation step, which is

```
for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
```

Simply ignore any edge that leads to a node in `X`, so:

```
for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) where w is not in X do
```

That is all you have to do.

---

### Reference implementation

Here is an implementation in **Java**:

```java
Node source = ...
Set<Node> nodesToIgnore = ...

Queue<Node> nodesToProcess = Collections.asLifoQueue(new ArrayDeque<>());
nodesToProcess.add(source); // add all starting nodes

Set<Queue> visitedNodes = new HashSet<>();
while (!nodesToProcess.isEmpty()) {
    // Settle node
    Node currentNode = nodesToProcess.poll();
    if (!visitedNodes.add(currentNode)) {
        continue; // Already visited before
    }
    
    // Do something with the node
    System.out.println(currentNode); // Replace by whatever you need
    
    // Relax all outgoing edges
    for (Node neighbor : currentNode.getNeighbors()) {
        if (nodesToIgnore.contains(neighbor)) {
            continue;
        }
        nodesToProcess.add(neighbor);
    }
}
```

---

### Stop when destination reached

The regular DFS algorithm explores the full graph. A simple modification can be done to stop it as soon as the destionation has been reached.

For that, just break the loop once you settled the destination:

```
// change this
v = S.pop()
// to
v = S.pop()
if (v == destination) {
    break;
}
```

In the Java code, that is:

```java
Node destination = ...
...
while (!nodesToProcess.isEmpty()) {
    // Settle node
    Node currentNode = nodesToProcess.poll();
    if (currentNode == destination) {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

### Path building

Constructing the final path is usually done via **backtracking**. Therefore, you simply have to remember for each node from where you came. For example by giving them a `parent` field or similar. Then you construct the path by reversly following them from `destination` back to `source`.

```java
...
while (!nodesToProcess.isEmpty()) {
    ...
    // Relax all outgoing edges
    for (Node neighbor : currentNode.getNeighbors()) {
        if (nodesToIgnore.contains(neighbor)) {
            continue;
        }

        neighbor.parent = currentNode; // remember parent
        nodesToProcess.add(neighbor);
    }
}

// Construct path by backtracking
List<Node> path = new ArrayList<>();
Node currentNode = destination;
while (currentNode != null) {
    path.add(currentNode);
    currentNode = currentNode.parent;
}

Collections.reverse(path);
```

---

### Full code

```java
Node source = ...
Node destination = ...
Set<Node> nodesToIgnore = ...

Queue<Node> nodesToProcess = Collections.asLifoQueue(new ArrayDeque<>());
nodesToProcess.add(source); // add all starting nodes

Set<Queue> visitedNodes = new HashSet<>();
while (!nodesToProcess.isEmpty()) {
    // Settle node
    Node currentNode = nodesToProcess.poll();
    if (currentNode == destination) {
        break;
    }
    if (!visitedNodes.add(currentNode)) {
        continue; // Already visited before
    }
    
    // Relax all outgoing edges
    for (Node neighbor : currentNode.getNeighbors()) {
        if (nodesToIgnore.contains(neighbor)) {
            continue;
        }

        neighbor.parent = currentNode; // remember parent
        nodesToProcess.add(neighbor);
    }
}

// Construct path by backtracking
List<Node> path = new ArrayList<>();
Node currentNode = destination;
while (currentNode != null) {
    path.add(currentNode);
    currentNode = currentNode.parent;
}

Collections.reverse(path);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Node currentNode = visitedNodes.poll();`  be `Node currentNode = nodesToProcess.poll();`  ?

Comment: @c0der Good spot. Corrected.

Comment: maybe is more easy to just color black the node of X and run dfs or bfs to find a path

Comment: @mario Note sure what you mean by that honestly. How would coloring nodes tell the algorithm to not consider it during exploration? You have to adjust the algorithm in a way that it ignores the nodes from `X`. There are various ways to achieve that, depending on how your specific implementation looks like. Either you do it like me, ignoring it during edge relaxation, or you wrap your graph behind an interface that pretends such nodes dont exist (implicitly filtering those edges), or you remove them entirely from the graph, ...